# Web Standards alternatives to Flex/Silverlight (I mean serious alternatives, not just JS framewoks)

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, silverlight, html

Is there a set of open standards technologies that I can use to achieve the same way of development as in Flex and Sivlerlight? I am talking about componentization, separation of concerns, rich graphics, states and effects . Please point out some tutorials and other resources if possible.

P.S. I KNOW that this is technically possible, so please do not respond by sending google search results or general JQuery tutorials. I've seen those already. I need to know how a Flex / Silverlight developer could design and implement an application in roughly the same way (imagine a rich HTML tag set, much like XAML/MXML, behind which stands JavaScript responsible for handling events and business logic. Think also about binding)

Comment: What do you mean by web standard?

Comment: HTML5 (although it is still something in between a standard and a revision) , JavaScript , CSS -  this kind of stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also check [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/) and their newly released [Designer](http://www.extjs.com/blog/?p=2946) is it "standards based" RIA JavaScript framework.

Here is a [list of examples](http://www.extjs.com/products/js/) showing what it is capable of.

For vector graphics you can use great JavaScript library for SVG: [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)

For raster graphics you have Canvas API and [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) library from Google for IE compatibility

If ExtJS charts are not enough for you, you can try [HighCharts](http://highcharts.com) which uses Canvas SVG or VML for rendering.

Comment: More and more I'm hearing about the goodness of ExtJS. I do not know why, but my experience with jQuery sucked big time. I am really looking forward to separating everything -server side code from html from client side components . This would require a robust IDE as well. All my respect to Notepad gurus out there, but Visual Studio, and Flex/Flash Builder are much easier for development. There is so much that can be done with Eclipse for example, yet I am still to see a good web application IDE (real IDE, with completion, highlighting, a good resource manager, etc )

Answer (score 2):

Stick to Flex for now !

Html 5 still Supports less active Browsers. Flex is Rich and As3 is a lot cleaner than js. Flex has a few very Advanced Frameworks.
bidirectional binding, dependency injection, all Kinds of fast mv* Frameworks.

So all in all Web development is far Away from Enterprise Development standards.

Guess its like in Adobe  Days we complained that Designers try to develop Language Not understanding the Concept of Enterprise Software and architectures. Its the Same now we have Web and Ajax devs at Hand :) it feels like they have less/no experience with Enterprise Standards ( Some maybe Even Architecture)  . So ! We will have to wait for js Frameworks to  improve A Lot , ext js feels like as2 and flex 2 - Pseudo Object orientation and clumsy getter/setter. Gwt  is pretty strong .. Knockout brings nice ideas. Angular js looks really promising. Jquery of course makes js bearable ... Yet it's just a small pill for a huge pita

A lot has to happen tho.

Answer (score 1):

GWT (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) comes to mind. Or maybe OpenLaszlo (http://www.openlaszlo.org/).

OpenLaszlo is quite close to Flex in phylosophy, but can target either the Flash VM or just plain Javascript. So it seems to fulfil the "web standard based" requirement.

I havent used OpenLaszlo since 2005, and at that time it definitly was not ready for a serious application. But things might have changed since then ...

Answer (score 1):

There is an upcoming project that brings Silverlight to all platforms. It is built using HTML5 and Javascript.  This project is still in an alpha phase, but promises a lot.  Check it out @ http://fayde.wsick.com.
DISCLOSURE: I am affiliated with this project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using all the new technology under the HTML5 umbrella, such as SVG, Canvas, HTML5 tags, CSS3, Transforms, Geolocation, Web Workers, Offline Storage etc. You can make some pretty amazing RIAs with that, and it's all open standards. Of course you'll be limiting yourself browser wise, at least initially.

Check out this HTML5 presentation written in HTML5 http://apirocks.com/html5/html5.html#slide1 (warning needs upto date browser such as Opera, Chrome or Safari).